# How do I run 3 foreach statements, after passing a condition?

Tags: php

I have three functions: `showActiveAdverts()`,`getActDefault()` and `getDefaultBanner()` and I want to run through all using a condition.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
$showBoard_arr = showActiveAdverts();

if($showBoard_arr){ 
$countBoard;
$advertTop .= '<div class="adSlot">' ;
$advertBottom .= '<div class="adSlot">' ;
foreach($showBoard_arr as $key => $showBoard){ //Get information from my DB
$countBoard += 1;
$advertId = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'id');
$advertTitle = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'title');
$advertImg = refineProfileImage(getAdLocation($showBoard, 'img_url'));
$advertUrl = $site_path . "clicks/" . $board_slug . "/" . $advertId;
$activeBoardIds = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'board_id');
// This is where I split the banners into two, i.e 3 top, three bottom
if ($countBoard <= 3){
$advertTop .= '<a href="'.$advertUrl.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.$site_path . "banners/" . $advertImg.'"></a>';

}
else {$advertBottom .= '<a href="'.$advertUrl.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.$site_path . "banners/" . $advertImg.'"></a>';}
}
/* What I want to do is to check if the function showActiveAdverts() does not return 6 advert.
*If this condition = true, then I want to do the getActDefault() function. But if the first 
*function (showActiveAdvert()) does not return any advert at all, then do getDefaultBanner().*/
$advertTop .= '</div>' ;
$advertBottom .= '</div>' ;

echo $advertTop;

}

?>
```

What I want to do is to check if the function `showActiveAdverts()` does not return 6 advert. If this condition = true, then I want to do the `getActDefault()` function. But if the first function (`showActiveAdvert()`) does not return any advert at all, then do `getDefaultBanner()`.
NB: For the other functions (`getActDefault()` and `getDefaultBanner`), I also need to do a foreach loop (the same way I did that of `showActiveAdverts`), so that the details will be accurately gotten from my DB. 
What is the best way to get this done.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this is what you want. I added some coments to the code to explain what I'm trying to do. This would go after the first foreach, before adding the `'</div>'`.

```
<?php
$showBoard_arr = showActiveAdverts();
//Defining this before the first function, in case no results.
$countBoard = 0;
$advertTop .= '<div class="adSlot">' ;
$advertBottom .= '<div class="adSlot">' ;

if($showBoard_arr){ 
    foreach($showBoard_arr as $key => $showBoard){ //Get information from my DB
    $countBoard += 1;
    $advertId = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'id');
    $advertTitle = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'title');
    $advertImg = refineProfileImage(getAdLocation($showBoard, 'img_url'));
    $advertUrl = $site_path . "clicks/" . $board_slug . "/" . $advertId;
    $activeBoardIds = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'board_id');
    if ($countBoard <= 3){
    $advertTop .= '<a href="'.$advertUrl.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.$site_path . "banners/" . $advertImg.'"></a>';

    }
    else {$advertBottom .= '<a href="'.$advertUrl.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.$site_path . "banners/" . $advertImg.'"></a>';}
    }
    //The first foreach is ended, now I check if there were not 6 adverts.
    if($countBoard != 6){ //If there are NOT exactly 6 adverts.
        $countBoard = 0;
        $advertTop = '<div class="adSlot">' ;
        $advertBottom = '<div class="adSlot">'; //Empty the first function adverts.
        $showBoard_arr = getActDefault(); //Get the adverts from this function.
        //Repeating foreach statement.
        foreach($showBoard_arr as $key => $showBoard){ //Get information from my DB
            $countBoard += 1;
            $advertId = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'id');
            $advertTitle = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'title');
            $advertImg = refineProfileImage(getAdLocation($showBoard, 'img_url'));
            $advertUrl = $site_path . "clicks/" . $board_slug . "/" . $advertId;
            $activeBoardIds = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'board_id');
            if ($countBoard <= 3){
            $advertTop .= '<a href="'.$advertUrl.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.$site_path . "banners/" . $advertImg.'"></a>';

            }
            else {$advertBottom .= '<a href="'.$advertUrl.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.$site_path . "banners/" . $advertImg.'"></a>';}
        }
    }
}
//So if we are here there are 2 options: 1) First or second function done.
//2) No results so we need the third function to be called.
if ($countBoard == 0){ //If there are no results at all.
    $showBoard_arr = getDefaultBanner(); //Get adverts from this other function.
     //Repeating foreach statement.
     foreach($showBoard_arr as $key => $showBoard){ //Get information from my DB
        $countBoard += 1;
        $advertId = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'id');
        $advertTitle = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'title');
        $advertImg = refineProfileImage(getAdLocation($showBoard, 'img_url'));
        $advertUrl = $site_path . "clicks/" . $board_slug . "/" . $advertId;
        $activeBoardIds = getAdLocation($showBoard, 'board_id');
        if ($countBoard <= 3){
        $advertTop .= '<a href="'.$advertUrl.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.$site_path . "banners/" . $advertImg.'"></a>';

        }
        else {$advertBottom .= '<a href="'.$advertUrl.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.$site_path . "banners/" . $advertImg.'"></a>';}
    }
}

//Now we are done, for x, y or z, the adverts are loaded. So we show them.
$advertTop .= '</div>' ;
$advertBottom .= '</div>' ;

echo $advertTop;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @AleOtero93. But please, where exactly do I place your code? Taking into consideration that I still have to do this: `// This is where I split the banners into two, i.e 3 top, three bottom
if ($countBoard <= 3){
$advertTop .= '<a href="'.$advertUrl.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.$site_path . "banners/" . $advertImg.'"></a>';

}
else {$advertBottom .= '<a href="'.$advertUrl.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.$site_path . "banners/" . $advertImg.'"></a>';}
}` for each of the functions.

Comment: You should replace your comment with your question (`/* What I want to do is to chec`... etc) with that code. But check my edit, so in case there were not 6 adverts, the function `getActDefault();` doesnt take them, and also reseting the counter...

Comment: Okay, so what you mean is that I should repeat the `foreach` statements again in this format: `foreach($showBoard_arr as $key => $showBoard){... etc?`

Comment: Yes, give me a minute. I'm making a little change to the code, I'll update the answer with it, so you could copy paste it, with comments of why I'm doing x or y

Comment: Done, it looks "messy", but that's only because the foreach is repeated 3 times. Did that solve your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93814/discussion-between-samuel-asor-and-aleotero93).